Dynamic extension of file for Tilelayer in Leaflet
I am wondering how to do it. I want to have different file extension depending on path to taht file. In my script below for example: white_orchard have .png files in z=2 and x=2.
// Funkcja do ustawiania odpowiedniej mapy na podstawie ścieżki
function setupMap() {
    let mapPath;
    let minZoom;
    let maxZoom;
    
    // Pobranie bieżącej ścieżki URL
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

    // Sprawdzenie ścieżki i ustawienie odpowiednich wartości
    if (currentPath.includes('/white_orchard/index.html')) {
        mapPath = '/resources/maps/white_orchard/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
        minZoom = 2;
        maxZoom = 5;
    } else if (currentPath.includes('/velen_novigrad/index.html')) {
        mapPath = '/resources/maps/hos_velen/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
        minZoom = 1;
        maxZoom = 6;
    } else {
        console.error('Nieznana ścieżka mapy');
        return;
    }

    // Obliczanie średniego zoomu
    const avgZoom = Math.round((minZoom + maxZoom) / 2);

    // Inicjalizacja mapy
    var map = L.map('mapid', {
        zoomControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        zoomSnap: 0.5,
        zoomDelta: 0.5
    }).setView([51.505, -0.09],avgZoom);

    // Dodanie kontrolek zoomu
    L.control.zoom({
        position: 'bottomright',
        zoomInTitle: 'Przybliż',
        zoomOutTitle: 'Oddal'
    }).addTo(map);

    // Okienko z koordynatami
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        var coords = e.latlng;
        var lat = coords.lat.toFixed(5);
        var lng = coords.lng.toFixed(5);
        console.log('Map clicked at:', lat, lng);
        L.popup()
            .setLatLng(coords)
            .setContent("Koordynaty: " + lat + ", " + lng)
            .openOn(map);
    });


    // Dodanie warstwy kafelków z opcją TMS
    L.tileLayer(mapPath, {
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        tms: true // Ustawienie odwrotnej numeracji kafelków
    }).addTo(map);
}

// Wywołanie funkcji po załadowaniu DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setupMap();
});


I tried to search for answers or use AI but it was in vain. I could use some advice on this particular problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@docker compose I want to know how to set dynamic extension to the files of tiles, depending on path.
